# Mock/Test Calls to Path.open

Tags: python, mocking, pathlib

I am attempting to write a unit test for a function that calls the `open` method on a `pathlib.Path`.  I am able to successfully mock the `open` method without issue, but verifying the function is having the correct behavior is difficult.  See the sample code below:

```py
def test_my_function(self):
    with patch.object(Path, 'open') as mock_open:
        my_function(*args)  # This function calls Path.open
```

When I introspect `mock_open` and review the `_mock_mock_calls` list, I am unable to find the string path of the file that is being written to.  The call history looks like this:

```py
[
    call(mode='w'),
    call().__enter__(),
    call().__enter__().write('<file contents>'),
    call().__enter__().flush(),
    call().__exit__(None, None, None),
]
```

Is there a way to test what path is being opened when `Path.open` is called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You replaced a method with a mock object. The issue with using a mock object here is that it *won't be bound to the `Path()` instance*. It'll be called, but there is no path back to the `Path()` instance (no pun intended).

Use a function to mock out `open()`, one that returns a [`mock_open()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.mock_open) to track further 'open file' use, functions *will* be bound when accessed on instances of `Path`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open

def test_my_function(self):
    opener = mock_open()
    def mocked_open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return opener(self, *args, **kwargs)
    with patch.object(Path, 'open', mocked_open):
        my_function(*args)  # This function calls Path.open
```

Now any `Path().open()` call will call the `opener` mock, recording all file interactions *and* the `Path()` object on which it was called:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open
>>> opener = mock_open()
>>> def mocked_open(self, *args, **kwargs):
...     return opener(self, *args, **kwargs)
...
>>> with patch.object(Path, 'open', mocked_open):
...     print(Path.open)
...     print(Path().open)
...     with Path().open() as f:
...         f.write('<file contents>')
...         f.flush()
...
<function mocked_open at 0x12026f5c0>
<bound method mocked_open of PosixPath('.')>
<MagicMock name='open().flush()' id='4834728928'>
>>> opener.mock_calls
[call(PosixPath('.')),
 call().__enter__(),
 call().write('<file contents>'),
 call().flush(),
 call().__exit__(None, None, None)]
```

Comment: With a slight modification to the `mocked_open` function to pass along `*args` and `**kwargs`, this worked perfectly.  Thank you!